# Padding value in android

Tags: android, padding

What is the meaning of this line of code?

android padding `Right = "@ dimen /activity_horizontal_margin"`.

What is `@dimen` referring to?

Answer (score 4):

you use the dimens file like this so that you can easily set many things to the same value (like a constant in code), or so you can override the value easily for different screen sizes.

dimen is located in `/ res / values /` in studio project like below

```
dimen.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <dimen name="action_button_min_width">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="indeterminate_progress_size">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Learn more about project structure in android studio
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html

Comment: Just to add to this-  you use the dimens file like this so that you can easily set many things to the same value (like a constant in code), or so you can override the value easily for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

dimen.xml is the file which you can set constant values for dimensions.

```
<resources>
   <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
   <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen> 
</resources>
```

It is usually created inside /res/values folder. If you don't find it there you can create and add values.

You may refer the following link for more details.

https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html